# Laravel Breeze Login/Register 419 Page Expired

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have a problem with my Laravel 9.x App (modifying from Laravel Breeze by switching from Tailwind to Bootstrap 5). Everything works fine in local, nothing serious happen. But when I deploy it on DO Server, the problem begin. The problem is, I got 419 Page Expired after doing a POST request (Login/Register/Logout) at a certain time. However, sometimes it works fine, I can register & login, but when I'm try to logout it returns 419 Page Expired. I've checked every single form to put `@csrf` and I still got 419 Page Expired. Then I'm trying to comment out the `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` on my live server, and every POST request works fine BUT, it didn't generate login session for me. Any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: clear the cache ```php artisan config:cache```

Answer (score -1):

> Then I'm trying to comment out the \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class on my live server, and every POST request works fine BUT, it didn't generate login session for me.

This sounds like you site isn't using HTTPS and the browser is discarding the cookies in between the requests.  This can also happen if you are using HTTPS but posting to HTTP (or vise-versa).

This behavior is expected if the cookie is set with the `Secure` flag. I've also seen some browsers do this anyway even if the Secure flag is not set.
In Laravel, this feature is not enabled by default.  It is enabled via the .ENV variable called `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE` being set to `true`. You can see this yourself by checking the `config/session.php` file.
This is a good feature to have enabled.

If you have setup any CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policies then you may want to make sure they are not blocking parts of the request as it can have a similar effect. Something like `https://www.example.com` is not considered the same as `https://example.com` if a wildcard was not used when defining the CORS policy.  These policies are a bit in-depth, so if none of this sounds familiar then you probably don't have one at all.  If unsure, an easy way to check is to look at the developer console in your browser. They typically complain in red text about something being blocked by CORS if it is happening.